# Multiple request in foreach php loop

Tags: php, ajax, request

I want to get the tweets of a list of users and save it to a db. The tweets are generated in a file called tweets.php which connects to the twitter api. If I have only one name, I can use file_get_contents to get the tweets and then insert them. But how do I do this if I have an array of users?

Below is an illustration of what I want to do. As far as I understand, it is not possible to use file_get_contens with a variable added (as in the script), but what should I use instaed. Is an ajax request the only way. Not quite sure how to combine ajax and php in this case, and I would perefer to stay in php.

```
$values = array(0 => 'Oscar', 1 => 'Peter', 2 => 'Paul');

 foreach($values as $value) {


 $tweetJson = file_get_contents('http://localhost/news/tweets.php?name='<?php echo .$value.    ?>)');


$tweetJson  = json_decode($tweetJson, true); 


$statement = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tweet (tweet, title) VALUES (?, ?)");

foreach($tweetJson  as $key => $value) {
$statement->execute(array($value['text'], $value['user']['name']));

}


}
```

Comment: You have a syntax problem `<?php echo $value  ?>` should be : `.$value.` Clear it first.

Comment: Ok, thank's for pointing that out! But is the approach with file_get_contents right?

Comment: Why not? If your `tweets.php` outputs valid and right json string, This means you can convert it to an array as you did it yourself. `var_dump($tweetJson)` after `file_get_contents` and add it to the question. So people can realize it.

Comment: Well, as I wrote in the question, I have read that you shouldn't send variables with file_get_contents. But maybe this is not correct.